# Can a mixin refer to values in the calling selector?

Tags: less

For example, I would like to be able to do this:

```
.bigfirstletter(@mag) {
  &:first-letter {
    font-size: [get_original_font_size] + @mag;
  }
}
```

But as far as I can see I have to do this, which is not as neat

```
.bigfirstletter(@fontsize, @mag) {
  &:first-letter {
    font-size: @fontsize + @mag;
  }
}
```

Do I have an alternative? Thank you for your help.

Comment: @fontsize doesn't have to be a parameter in your mixin, it can be defined as a global variable - which makes sense anyway to have such a thing.

Comment: @bzx Thanks. Bootstrap, which I'm using, doesn't define vars for the h1-6 tags but I could add them. Still curious to know if this is possible, though.

Comment: probably via JS which is possible in lesscss, but anyway seems quirky to me.. re:Bootstrap, take a look at type.less - you have stuff defined there for h1-h6

Comment: I beg to differ :-) https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/type.less

Comment: you're right, well, can't you just change those px values to @baseFontSize * 2.0 / 1.7 / 1.5 .. etc?

Comment: I may do that. But I am still curious about the answer to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

damn it was simpler than I thought :)

```
.bigfirstletter(@mag) {
  &:first-letter {
    font-size: 1em * @mag;
  }
}
```

1em will simply inherit whatever it is defined for element, and you just set your magnification. **I changed the plus sign to multiply on purpose** as with this you're going to have better control over font size - @mag=1.0 for same font size, @mag=1.5 for 50% bigger, and so on..

---

sorry about the answer below, for some reason I didn't see that you're using first-letter in the example provided (doh!)

take a look at :first-letter CSS pseudo class - [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#first-letter)

Comment: thanks for the link. But I would still like to know whether it's possible.